# Compile serialport module using babel and webpack

Tags: webpack, electron, babeljs, node-serialport

Im running an old version of electron (v6) and node v16 and I need to use the latest serialport (v11) module which contains a newer syntax like optional chaining etc. I am using both babel and webpack with the following configuration but the serialport module does not seem to compile for me.  This is the config that I am currently using.

**babel.config.js**

```
    presets: [
      [
        require('@babel/preset-env'),
        {
          targets: {electron: require('electron/package.json').version},
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          corejs: 2
        }
      ]
    ]
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
    module: {
        target: 'electron-renderer'
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules\/(?!@serialport)/, 
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
              }
            }
         }]
    }
```

Is there something that I am missing as I still get `Unexpected token .` on the following line
`return (this.port?.isOpen ?? false) && !this.closing`

Ive tried various webpack and babel configurations and also researched possible version conflicts all of which I cant get to work.

Any help would be much appretiated

Comment: Babel should already handle optional chaining with its [default config](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDMBXANug3AKFJWAIyXgH4A6YLIA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&modules=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.23.10&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D).

Comment: @Arkellys thanks for your comment. I cant understand why this would not be working then

Comment: Why would you try to compile `serialport` with a config made for the renderer? `serialport` is a NodeJS library, it will not work on browser side, and certainly not with the target you use anyway.

Comment: @Arkellys according to serialport 'Since v10 we should work in both the main and render processes' of electron.